# Routes file not properly loaded

Tags: php, laravel

I have just installed a new installation of Laravel using composer as per the laravel docs. The documentation refers to the app/routes.php file which is used to map routes to controllers or closed functions. First, there was no app/routes.php file so I created one. Now the routes I've copied from the laravel documentation aren't being found when accessing via the browser. In fact the app/routes.php file isn't even being found by the application as I have put a die statement in there and nothing. It has nothing to do with .htaccess. I am using the default .htaccess and redirects are working. I thought maybe it has something to do with the composer.json autoload array so I have tested that and nothing. Not a jot. Either I'm being thick or there is something fundamental which isn't being explained in the docs. I'm running the latest version of laravel. Any ideas?

Comment: Open your composer.json file and see which laravel version you just got. If it's really you "just installed" you've downloaded the 5.0 and are somewhat looking at the 4.2 version docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel changed the folder structure with its latest release (which is version 5):

- In 4.2: `app/routes.php`
- In 5.0: `app/Http/routes.php`

There's also a few things you need to do in order for a Laravel Project to work. First (and this is the method I use) create a symbolic link to your project's `public` folder:

```
ln -s /path/to/webroot/example_app/public /path/to/webroot/example
```

Next, change the permissions on your `storage` folder:

```
chmod 777 -R storage
```

You should now be able to access `localhost/example` and the Laravel 5 welcome page should show up. Usually I call my project `example_app` and create a link to a folder called `example`, so I can easily access it via `localhost/example`

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5, the routes file is located elsewhere: app/Http/routes.php.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that I had tried using the Http/routes.php file as well and nothing. It is actually version 5 I'm using which explains why there was no app/routes.php. However I had found Http/routes.php, tried the same procedure with that and nothing. The application is not even finding the file. I am seeing a lot of issues to do with mod_rewrite etc being talked about but it has definitely got nothing to do with that,I've tested using Redirect etc and each browser call is being routed to index.php as it should. I am using the basic example from the laravel 5 routing docs to test

Comment: I now have it working. I set the storage and vendor folders to 777 and it solved the problem so thanks to Tim Lewis for his answer. I then got a mcrypt error message because mcrypt wasn't installed on my version of ubuntu (14.4). I have now installed it and we are up and running.I've not had to symlink to another folder as suggested and it appears to be working fine?? Maybe that's round the corner!

Comment: @jonnjo2005 Depending on how you have your environment set up, you sometimes don't have to use symlinks. I do because that's how I was taught, but if you can run it without, then don't worry about it. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Basically I did chmod 777 on the storage and vendor files and it started working